# Мобильная версия сайта не проходит проверку google console

Tags: веб-программирование, webpack

При запуске сайта версии для мобильных устройств возникла ошибка:
1)В метатеге viewport должно быть значение device-width
2)Интерактивные элементы расположены слишком близко
3)Слишком маленький шрифт (однако 16px, а минимимум должен быть 12)

Использую конструктор hoster.by

Comment: Сочувствуем, а в чём вопрос-то?

Comment: Шрифт установлен верный, однако, гугл проверка и яндекс проверка показывает, что шрифт не подходит(слишком мелкий для телефонных устройств)

Comment: Значит он на самом деле неверный, а вы что-то где-то не заметили